# Show that $\frac{a}{a-\epsilon} \geq \exp(b\epsilon)$

Tags: calculus

I need to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a-\epsilon} \geq \exp(b\epsilon)
\end{align}
is true, for $0<\epsilon < a<b$. Is this doable in a general way?

Edit: 
Sorry, I forgot to metion $ab=1$, which rather gives
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a-\epsilon} \geq \exp\left(\frac{\epsilon}{a}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: It think this makes no sense: $\epsilon = 1, b = 10,$ and $a = 2$ contradicts the inequality.

Comment: This is obviously false for $\epsilon>a$ (the left side becomes negative). So you should have some stronger constraint. This constraint will have to involve $b$ as well, because for fixed $a,\epsilon$ you can make the right side blow up by increasing $b$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add $a>\epsilon$.

Comment: Again, that's still not good enough. Fix $a$, let $\epsilon=1/b$ and send $b \to \infty$. The right side remains $e$ but the left side converges to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fairly easy for you to see that $e^x \le \dfrac 1{1-x}$ if $0 < x < 1$.  Then
$$ \frac{a}{a-\epsilon} = \frac{1}{1 - \epsilon/a} \ge \exp(\epsilon/a) \ge \exp(b\epsilon)$$ provided that $0 < \epsilon < a$ and $ab \le 1$.

It is false in general, though.

Comment: You can get the first statement by comparing the power series; $e^x-\frac{1}{1-x}$ cancels out the first two terms and then consists of negative terms thereafter.

Comment: Thanks and sorry guys. I forgot to mention $ab=1$ as well.

Comment: Is $e^x < 1/(1-x)$ if $0<x<1$ true, because of $\lim_{x \to 0} \{e^x=1 \wedge 1/(1-x) = 1\}$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} \{e^x=e \wedge 1/(1-x) = \infty\}$.